# Dynamic selectors for external jQuery slider navigation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, anythingslider

Very straightforward question:

I've built a slider with (dynamic amount of slides), with a sidebar for expanded navigation (`#slidercontrols`). Every child of this navigation sidebar should link to their own corresponding slide.

I'm currently working with [a very quick, simple setup](http://jsfiddle.net/qbahamutp/TsJCP/) which just repeats the same code for each slide and works just fine, but I'm sure we'll all agree that it's a very messy solution. Not very DRY. For educational reasons, I'm curious how you pro's would solve this matter :)

How could you build a simple loop that directs #slidernavigation child X to slide X? You'd need some sort of dynamic selector that I'm unfamiliar with...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbahamutp/TsJCP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at first I would suggest that you use just one selector. Then how to recognize the index? There are many ways, but in this case one way could be storing data to div element with jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Then when you click any div, you just take the index from the saved data and use that.

If you know that the divs are always in indexed order, you could just use .index() aswell.
Example with .index() http://jsfiddle.net/TsJCP/1/

Comment: Thank you both so much for your feedback :) The .index()-feature was exactly the kind of feature I was looking for. And although the data feature also was a wonderful way to go, I'll definitely keep this feature in mind - it's bound to come in handy.

Comment: I love discovering previously unknown features like this. Struggling to do something the hard way, just to find out that jQuery already thought of a natively embedded function to do _just that_. God bless the internets.

Comment: @Adrian: The [newest version](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) of AnythingSlider has a lot more options and callbacks available. I put together [an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/TsJCP/2/) for you which uses the `onSlideComplete` callback to update navigation controls.

Comment: @fudgey, that is a fantastic addition, man. I never thought you'd be able to do that with such little code..! Perfect. Thanks so much, man :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Quk7/5/

add attribute rel to the slider control with the number of the slide with `$.each()` or use some other logic to do it (like generate indexes in the html e.g. get them from a db). You can use it as a selector in jQuery and CSS aswell. e.g. `.article[rel="1"]{ color: red !important; }`

Generated markup will look like

```
<div class="article gotoslide-1 currentslide" rel="1">
                <h4>Past NedTrain bij jou?</h4>
                <p>Bekijk met welke functies en .</p>
</div>
```

and use `$(this).attr('rel')` in onclick to get the index.

```
$(function(){
    $('#contentslider ul').anythingSlider({
        width            : 320,
        height            : 215,
        startStopped    : true,
        forwardText        :"&nbsp;",
        backText        :"&nbsp;",
        delay            : 6000,
        easing            : 'easeInOutExpo',
//                    buildArrows        : false,
        hasgTags        : false,
//                    appendControlsTo: "#slidercontrols",
        buildNavigation    : false
    });

    $("#slidercontrols .article").each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('rel',i+1);
    });
    // Slide navigation. 
    $("#slidercontrols .article").click(function(){
        $('#contentslider ul').anythingSlider($(this).attr('rel'), function(slider){ /* alert('Now on page ' + slider.currentPage); */ });
        $(".currentslide").removeClass("currentslide");
        $(this).addClass("currentslide");
        return false;
    });
});
```

You might want to use `$("#slidercontrols .article").live('click',...);` if you plan to dynamically add slides